# How does WorldEdit handle brushes?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to find out how the **Bukkit** version of WorldEdit handles brushes. I've been looking at the source code on GitHub, but I couldn't find anythig useful. I've tried to recreate the effect, but I can only get it to work when I'm in interaction reach of the target block.

This is about as close as it gets in the source code:

```
} else if (action == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) {
    if (we.handleRightClick(player)) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```

(WorldEdit/worldedit-bukkit/src/main/java/com/sk89q/worldedit/bukkit/WorldEditListener.java, line 143-147)

There are some other parts of code that get very close. I've also looked in /worldedit-core, but nothing there either.

Could someone help me here?

Edit: This is how I try to do it:

```
public static void onRightClick (PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            Location location = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
            if (event.getItem() != null) {
                if (event.getItem().getItemMeta().equals(ItemManager.wand.getItemMeta())) {
                    Player player = event.getPlayer();
                    player.getWorld().doStuff(location);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit #2: what I'm most curious about is: How does WE select the location to apply the brush if you are outside of interaction reach?

Comment: You need to first locate the interacted with block (you've got a good start there), then you need to deduce applying a "brush" in mathematical terms. WE makes their own `Brush` objects that track size and type, etc. The application of such things is really up to you, but it's basically just a math problem reapplied. If you're not comfortable with object-oriented concepts, this will become a bit hard to do for more than 1 brush.

Comment: Sure, but what I most want to know is how WE selects the location to apply the brush if you are outside of interaction reach? Forgot to mention this in the post, adding it now

Comment: It's a simple raytrace, `BlockIterator` would achieve what you're looking for. Just iterate in the player's direction until you hit something that isn't `Material.AIR`

Comment: @Rogue Thanks, I made some code that doesn't work, I added it to the post

Comment: BlockIterator code looks fine, you just need to debug the rest. First thing that looks wrong is your item comparison (you shouldn't compare objects with `==`)

Comment: @Rogue thanks, that was the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `BlockIterators` for this. The final code looks like this:

```
public class BoomWandEvent implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public static void onRightClick (PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK || event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) {
            if (player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().equals(ItemManager.explosionWand)) {
                Location eyePos = player.getEyeLocation();
                BlockIterator raytracer = new BlockIterator(eyePos, 0.0D, player.getClientViewDistance() * 16);
                while (raytracer.hasNext()) {
                    Location location = raytracer.next().getLocation();
                    if (player.getWorld().getBlockAt(location).getType() != Material.AIR && player.getWorld().getBlockAt(location).getType() != Material.CAVE_AIR && player.getWorld().getBlockAt(location).getType() != Material.VOID_AIR) {
                        player.getWorld().createExplosion(location, 4f);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Rogue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786065/rogue) for helping!